# Show Random Text in HTML Input on Reload

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently a rookie coder, so I will need some help.

I would like to show a random string of text in an  html field on page load/reload. I would like it to pick a random string of text from a list that I have.

Oh, also, by the way, could I have a JsFiddle link (if possible)

~ Thanks, Calo

Comment: Show us some of your attempts

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a free coding service. Read [ask], and take a [tour]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it. You can simply add more sentences to the array holding the samples.

```js
var texts = [
  "I am a sentence.",
  "Some nice stuff.",
  "I am random too!"
];

document.getElementById('randomText').value = texts[Math.floor(Math.random()*texts.length)];
```

```html
<input type="text" id="randomText">
```

Comment: That really helps. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

On every reload it will show random number.

```js
// find elements
var banner = $("#banner-message-text")
banner.val(parseInt(Math.random()*18546876546));
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <input type="text" id="banner-message-text"/>
</div>
```

Comment: It isn't an <input> field though. Thanks for trying though :)

Comment: Sorry to say this, but I need to set a specific list of text to randomly select from. Sorry! <:|

Answer (score 2):

```
let messages = ["Hi", "Hey", "Hello", "Please make some attempts", "holla"];
 // We can use inbuilt Math object to perform mathematical operations.
 // to get a random number between 0 and the total size of messages array, we can use it as follows. 
 // Math.floor will return the largest integer which is less than or equal to that random number.
    let message = messages[Math.floor(Math.random()*messages.length)];

// to select your input element and set default value, you can do
$('input').val(message);
```

Ref : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @bugs, while answering I thought comments are self-explanatory.

Comment: Explain the `Math` methods and why multiplying by `messages.length` for future reader to better understand your code and why it works.